# How to produce two asterisks, asterism ∗, ⁑, ⁂

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to create tags for equations as sequential asterisks

```
            a+b=c                                   (∗)
            x+y=z                                   (⁑)
            i+j=k                                   (⁂)
```

How would you typeset them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the numbering with asterisks you have in mind, you can define it without `\substack` that doesn't seem to be the best tool.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\stars}{}% just for safety
\DeclareRobustCommand{\stars}[1]{\stars@{#1}}
\newcommand{\stars@}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\or\stars@one\or\stars@two\or\stars@three\or\stars@four
  \else ??\fi
}
\newcommand{\stars@char}{$\scriptstyle*$}
\newcommand{\stars@base}[1]{%
  $\m@th\vcenter{\offinterlineskip\ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr#1\crcr}}$%
}
\newcommand{\stars@one}{%
  \stars@base{\stars@char}%
}
\newcommand{\stars@two}{%
  \stars@base{\stars@char\cr\stars@char}%
}
\newcommand{\stars@three}{%
  \stars@base{\stars@char\cr\stars@char\stars@char}%
}
\newcommand{\stars@four}{%
  \stars@base{\stars@char\stars@char\cr\stars@char\stars@char}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
p+q=w \\
a+b=c \label{eq:1} \tag{\stars{1}} \\
x=y   \label{eq:2} \tag{\stars{2}} \\
x=y   \label{eq:3} \tag{\stars{3}} \\
x=y   \label{eq:4} \tag{\stars{4}}
\end{gather}

Text \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2} and \eqref{eq:3} and \eqref{eq:4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how `\hfil##\hfil` works?

Comment: @antshar It is the template for the single column in `\ialign`, the analog of `c` in `tabuular`

Comment:  interesting. Where can I read more about it?

Comment: @antshar In the TeXbook or in TeX by Topic (`texdoc texbytopic`); look for `\halign`, which is the basic TeX structure for alignments.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, the character ⁂ (U+2042) is not declared in the MathClass.txt file, so it is missing in almost all Unicode math fonts. But the character ⁑ (U+2051) is present here and there are Unicode math fonts they include it, for example `STIXMath-Regular.otf`. My example uses this font and defines ⁂ as active character equivalent to the macro `\threeasts` which is defined by `\halign` and completes these three *.

The example uses OpTeX:

```
\loadmath{[stixmath-regular]}
\fontfam[termes]

\def\threeasts{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr$*$\cr$**$\cr}}}
\catcode`⁂ = 13 \let ⁂ = \threeasts

$$
  a + b = c \eqno (*)
$$
$$
  x + y = z \eqno (⁑)
$$
$$
  i + j = k \eqno (⁂)
$$

\bye
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplification of egreg’s great answer that uses the Unicode characters:  It works in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make it an error if a glyph is missing.
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup} % Load unicode-math and New Computer Modern

\newfontfamily\symbolfont{DejaVu Serif}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newcommand\texttwostars{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2051}}} % ⁑
\newcommand\textthreestars{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2042}}} % ⁂
\newcommand\textdoublequestion{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2047}}} % ⁇

\newcommand{\stars}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\or\textasteriskcentered\or\texttwostars\or\textthreestars
  \else\textdoublequestion\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
p+q=w \\
a+b=c \label{eq:1} \tag{\stars{1}} \\
x=y   \label{eq:2} \tag{\stars{2}} \\
x=y   \label{eq:3} \tag{\stars{3}}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern + DejaVu Serif sample]